# не пойму в чем ошибка. не сходится с ожидаемым результатом (на калькуляторе)

Tags: java

```
/*дано целое число n; 
вычислить последовательность s = 1/cos(1)+1/(cos(1)+cos(2))+ 1/((cos(1)+cos(2)+cos(3)+..+cos(n))*/
package drug.zadacha;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double sumCos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sumCos += Math.cos(i);
        }
        System.out.println(calc(n, sumCos));
    }
    private static double calc(int n, double sumCos) {
        if(n==1) {
            return 1.85;
        }
        else {
            return 1/(sumCos - Math.cos(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// как-то так вроде получилось , в Вашей логике не разобрался !

```
/*дано целое число n;
вычислить последовательность s = 1/cos(1)+1/(cos(1)+cos(2))+ 
1/((cos(1)+cos(2)+cos(3)+..+cos(n))*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double sumCos = 0;
        double tempResult = 0;
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sumCos += Math.cos(i);
            tempResult = 1 / sumCos;
            result += tempResult;
        }
//            System.out.println(calc(n, sumCos));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
//        private static double calc(int n, double sumCos) {
//            if(n==1) {
//                return 1.85;
//            }
//            else {
//                return 1/(sumCos - Math.cos(n));
//            }

}
```

Comment: Посмотрите, у вас считает под одним знаменателем все.

Comment: Надо, чтобы считало сумму дробей 1/(cos1)+1/((cos1)+(cos2)) + 1/(cos(1)+cos(2)+cos(3) Моя логика заключалась в том что я сначала суммировал знаменатель (то есть начал с конца решал). Далее перевернул дробь. Соответственно я нашел последнюю дробь послеловательности. Далее при каждом вызове функции я вычитал из знаменателя последний член (это косинус последнего элемента). Я не пойму почему при вводе 4, он выдает ответ с минусом. При вводе 3 значение совпадает с калькулятором.

Comment: тут вопрос только в математике , я продолжил/изменил вашу цепочку , в цикле при каждой итерации добавляется одна дробь в промежуточный результат. попробуйте вручную заполнить Ваш цикл и на бумаге посчитать , может видно будет просчёт !